# gram-schmidt process on standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the Least Squares Approximation $g(x)=a+bx$ of the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.
I know I have to do the Gram-Schmidt process first but I can't seem to get the right answer. I've been trying to do the process on the standard basis $\{1,x\}$, am I supposed to be doing the process on a different basis?

Comment: What is the underlying space and inner product?

Comment: That's all I have for the question.

Comment: That information is crucial to solving the problem. How can you do Gram-Schmidt if you don't know what inner product to use? I could make a guess that the functions in question are defined on e.g. the interval $[0,1]$ and that $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\mathsf dx$, but that would only be a guess.

Comment: The interval is [1,4] but I'm not given the inner product. I think g(x) is used to find the least squares approximation, not for the gram schmidt process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that we are working in $L^2[1,4]$, with inner product
$$\langle f,g\rangle =\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\mathsf dx. $$
The norm of a given element $f\in L^2[1,4]$ is then
$$\|f\| = \sqrt{\int_1^4 f^2(x)\mathsf dx}.$$
To find an orthogonal basis for $$\mathcal P_1[1,4] = \{a+bx : a,b,\in\mathbb R\}, $$ let the first element be $1$. Projecting $x$ onto this element and subtracting $x$ (i.e. Gram-Schmidt procedure), we have
$$x - \frac{\langle x,1\rangle}{\langle 1,1\rangle}1 = x - \frac{\int_1^4 x\mathsf dx}{\int_1^4 \mathsf dx} = x-\frac52. $$
Our orthonormal basis is then
$$ \left(\frac{1}{\|1\|}, \frac{x-\frac52}{\left\|x-\frac52\right\|}\right) = \left(\frac1{\sqrt3}, \frac23 x-\frac53 \right).$$
Denote these basis elements by $e_1$ and $e_2$. To find the function $g\in\mathcal P_1[1,4]$ that minimizes $\|f-g\|$, we  project $f$ onto $\mathcal P_1[1,4]$:

$$
\begin{align*}
g(x) &= \langle f,e_1\rangle e_1 + \langle f,e_2\rangle e_2\\
&= \int_1^4 x^{\frac12}\mathsf dx + \left(\int_1^4\left(\frac23 x-\frac 53\right)\mathsf dx\right)\left(\frac23 x-\frac 53\right)\\
&= \frac{14}3 + \frac{22}{45}\left(\frac23 x-\frac 53\right)\\
&= \frac{44}{135}x + \frac{104}{27}.
\end{align*}
$$